# Why does using AsNoTracking() still give an error for duplicates?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Either I don't understand how AsNoTracking is supposed to work, or I'm doing something wrong. From what I've read it's supposed to pull the record without saving it in the EF cache, effectively allowing me to re-add it as a new row.

I have this bit of code, and I'm changing the primary key, but when I try to save the changes, it's throwing an exception saying that it can't add it because of a duplicate key. The weird thing is the exception lists the OLD id instead of the newly generated one.

Any thoughts? I'm pulling out my hair.

```
var coverage = db.Coverages.AsNoTracking().Where(c => c.ID == oldCoverageID).FirstOrDefault();
coverage.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
coverage.PolicyID = newPolicy.ID;

db.Coverages.Add(coverage);

db.SaveChanges(); // erroring here
```

---

### Edit:

As it turns out, I was using a sub-entity of the original record to grab the ID before calling that method. I'm assuming that even though I called AsNoTracking() on the original record as well.. the EF still caches the sub-entities. And there was no method exposed to call it. So, what I did was grabbed the ID using another call to the DB instead of using the sub entity. I don't know why it worked. But it did. If someone could explain either a better solution or why the problems exists, please do. I'll award the answer to whoever helps figure out why EF behaves this way.

To add context here are the ways I am/was grabbing the oldID before sending it to that method.

```
// fetching the id this way gave me fits
Guid oldCoverageID = existingPolicy.Coverage.Where(c => c.PolicyID == "policy id").First().ID;

// grabing the id doing this made everything happy
Guid oldCoverageID = db.Coverages.Where(c => c.POLICYHDRID == oldPolicyID).FirstOrDefault().ID;
```

I also did AsNoTracking() when fetching the policy as well.. I wouldn't think that would matter.. but just throwing out as much info as I can.

Comment: I've just done a simple test and looks like the code should work. `AsNoTracking` seems able to help clone entity OK. Now not really sure your code throws exception.

Comment: See my edit.. I'm not sure either. That is the ONLY code change I did to make it work.